# Unable to run the x-executable file

Tags: 14.04

I am unable to run an x-executable file, Cyberoam crclient file for Linux.
I have made crclient an executable and properties shows that it is an executable.  When I try to execute it, `bash: ./crclient: No such file or directory`.
When I  try to run in GUI it shows nothing.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `stat crclient`. Run the command in your `CyberoamLinuxClient` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Cyberroam has no GUI, you run it through the terminal. You have an error because you are not in the program's directory. Find where cyberroam is located. Navigate your way through the terminal to the folder, and run `./crclient` with an option(listed in the readme file). Or, right click in folder, click "open terminal (here)" and run `./crclient`.

Comment: i have done it in the program directory itself

Answer (score 0):

1. Download

   ```
   cd
   wget http://download.cyberoam.com/solution/optionals/CyberoamLinuxClient.tar.gz
   ```
2. Extract

   ```
   tar xf CyberoamLinuxClient.tar.gz
   ```
3. Run (replace `username` and `interface`)

   ```
   cd CyberoamLinuxClient
   ./crclient -u <username> -i <interface>
   ```

   Read more [here](http://kb.cyberoam.com/default.asp?id=1870&Lang=1&SID=).